Why does this presumably 15A GFCI say its a 20A receptacle?
This has straight slots (not T-shaped), and so it looks like a 15A.  But the inscriptions are misleading.  On the top,

CLASS A 20A GFCI 2P/125V/60HZ.

and on the bottom

SPEC GRADE ShockSentry 15A receptacle

The picture is hard to see but I promise that's what it says!  Made by Cooper.


It's not a 20A receptable because it won't accept a 20A plug.

Most 15 amp receptacles can be on 20 amp circuits.  They can pass though the twenty amps(to a 20 amp receptacle).

@crip659 No, not most. All. It’s an NEC requirement.

@nobody  Do you know how long it has been a requirement?  just for my information/learning.

A UL requirement is that all 15A faced receptacles (i.e. NEMA 5-15 sockets) must have 20A passthru.
The companion rule to this is NEC 210.21(B)(3) which allows 15A receptacles on 20A circuits.
Thus, the receptacle may have a 12.5A and a 7.2A device plugged into it.  Or there may be 12A here and 7A on the next socket (this is called pass-through).  Or 0A here and 12A and 7A on subsequent sockets.  Etc.
Further, GFCIs have a feature called "downline protection" which allows them to protect other outlets beyond the GFCI (this is the ONLY use for the "Load" terminals). Therefore the GFCI must also have 20A pass-through.

A 15 Amp GFCI receptacle is built to handle 20 Amps (as in the gfci part) because you can put it on a 20A breaker.
However they are sold with 15A faceplate because that's what most appliances use and a lot of older houses have 15A circuits that you shouldn't put a 20A receptacle on so the manufacturer makes you pay a premium for the T-slot receptacle.

Also, it may be used to protect a 20A outlet on the load side even if it only accepts 15A plugs directly. I'm using one in exactly that situation; an inside GFCI protects my garden outlet.
